# CentOS 6 - Find KVM VM with HW addr

Tags: networking, kvm-virtualization, centos6, packet-capture

We are running KVM VM's (Linux & Windows) on our CentOS 6 & 7 hypervisors.
Sometimes we are noticing a lot of packets going in or out.

Now I want to see which IP address or network adapter causes this.
I use `iptraf` to see the in & out rate of packets on our hypervisors, but this only shows the `HW addr` of the VM's.

How and where do I see the IP address or network adapter name with only a `HW addr`?

The `HW addr` looks like this:

> HW addr: 001c7300**9* on em1

Without the stars, I replaced them, but they are also numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `virsh domiflist` to show the network interfaces and MACs associated with a specific virtual machines.

Alternatively, you can `grep -i aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff /etc/libvirt/qemu/*.xml` (where `aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff` is the MAC you are searching).

Comment: Thank you very much! This helped me a lot!